# Java RSA Decrypt BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, sha256, rsa-sha256

I'm working on small tool to encrypt and decrypt data base on RSA Algo.
I used openSSL to create private and public key. then import to java code and encrypt and decrypt data.
Fisrt, I use follow command to generate public and private key

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key private_key.pem -out public_key.cer -days 3650
```

**Next, get public key from file:**

```
    private static PublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKey) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String publicKeyPEM = getKey(publicKey);
        return getPublicKeyFromString(publicKeyPEM);
    }

    private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String publicKeyPEM = key;
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "");
        byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);
        CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded);
        X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
        return cer.getPublicKey();
    }
```

**And private key from file**

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String privateKey) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String privateKeyPEM = getKey(privateKey);
        return getPrivateKeyFromString(privateKeyPEM);
    }

    private static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromString(String key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String privateKeyPEM = key;
        privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
        privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(privateKeyPEM);
        ASN1Sequence primitive = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Sequence
                .fromByteArray(data);
        Enumeration<?> e = primitive.getObjects();
        BigInteger v = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();

        int version = v.intValue();
        if (version != 0 && version != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong version for RSA private key");
        }
        /**
         * In fact only modulus and private exponent are in use.
         */
        BigInteger modulus = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger publicExponent = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger privateExponent = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger prime1 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger prime2 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger exponent1 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger exponent2 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        BigInteger coefficient = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
        RSAPrivateKeySpec spec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
        PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(spec);

        return pk;
    }
```

**Then encrypt**

```
private static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        try {
            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            // encrypt the plain text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

**And decrypt**

```
private static String decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey key) {
        try {
            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

            // decrypt the text using the private key
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decryptTxt = cipher.doFinal(text);
            return new String(decryptTxt);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }
```

So, encryption success, but in decrypt, I got following exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at pgp.RSAUtil.decrypt(RSAUtil.java:46)
    at pgp.RSAUtil.getDecryptData(RSAUtil.java:67)
    at pgp.PGPForm$2.actionPerformed(PGPForm.java:109)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
    at pgp.PGPForm$2.actionPerformed(PGPForm.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

So, without `-sha256 in public key` when run `openSSL`, this source code work fine. When I add it, I got exceptions above.

Any solutions? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Could you try setting `ALGORITHM="RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` or using OAEP with `ALGORITHM="RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"` ?

Comment: Hi, I tried both and got exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key

Comment: "Empty key" is certainly not related to the algorithm. Check that you are loading the keys correctly